# I'm getting no implicit conversion of string into integer error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view-helpers

```
path_to = build_twitter_content_influencer_path(@influencer,
                                                url: @feed.try(:[], "account_link"),
                                                content: @feed.try(:[], "link"),
                                                identity: @feed.try(:[], "social_account_account_name"))
link_to "+", path_to, method: "post", class: "button-plus", target: "_blank"
```

Is there something wrong with this link? Or a variable? The controller?

Answer (score 2):

See this example

```
 > array = [1,2,3,4,5]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
 > array["asd"]
TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer
```

Arrays cannot have `String` as `indices`. To have `any-object` as indices, there is another data-structure called `associative-array` AKA `Hash`.

---

In your case you have tried to use `string` as `index` for `Array`, so this happened.

here `@feed` is a collection, behaves like `array`, so make sure you extract out individual `feed` object out from `collection` and try `@feed.try(:[], "link")`

```
@the_feed = @feed.first
@the_feed.try(:[], "link")
```